# Batch Scripting deployment application

Tags: shell, batch-processing

Im Currently in job right to do some batch deploy application btw I'm assigned in Computer Laboratory in school I want to get some tips to how to start deploying application in multiple computer what networking knowledge need to know thank you

To answer your question

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Your question is likely to have different opinionated answers and is also a request for tools and research which are all off-topic. Good luck.